# как в java можно отредактировать шрифты

Tags: java, шрифты, otf

Мне требуется отредактировать шрифт через Java и после редактирования сохранить. 
Я попытался прочитать файл шрифтов как обычный текстовый файл, но там много непонятных символов. 
Сам фал шрифтов в формате otf.
Можно пример кода или какой класс использовать для этого?